# ORM can't fit (even though it should)

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

When I try to save

```
entLog = EntityNew("CCF_MiscLog", {LogType = arguments.LogType, CCFLocationID = this.ccflocationid, onTable = arguments.onTable, message = arguments.message, CreateBy = variables.by});

EntitySave(entLog);
}
```

I get a failure

```
Cannot convert the value 140.0 to byte because it cannot fit inside a byte.
```

I know that it is referring to `CCFLocationID = this.ccflocationid`

This field is a tinyint in SQL server. It can store numbers up to 255. I have tried

```
<cfproperty name="ccflocationid" ormtype="int">
```

but that does not help. Is there any way to get this to cooperate?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the value in an `int()` function? If you need a decimal, use a different data type.

```
entLog = EntityNew("CCF_MiscLog", {LogType = arguments.LogType, CCFLocationID = int(this.ccflocationid), onTable = arguments.onTable, message = arguments.message, CreateBy = variables.by});

EntitySave(entLog);
}
```